# Route login not defined, i keep getting this error when trying to make the page redirect to the login if the admin user is currently not logged in

Tags: php, laravel

this code is in my handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
   switch($guard){
       case 'admin':
        return redirect(to:'/admin/login');
        break;

        default:
        return redirect(to:'/login');
        break;
   }
```

this is my middleware in dashboard controller

```
 public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware(middleware:'auth:admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install auth package? if you installed it, you have to put auth routes in routes folder in web.php file

```
Auth::routes()
```

If your are going to define it yourself, you can create a new route in this file

```
Route::get("/login",[AuthController,"login"]);
```

If You are going to auth package, you can run this command:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then you should put auth routes in web.php file:

```
Auth::routes()
```

Comment: this worked out but now i am getting a new error. Call to undefined function App\Exceptions\array_get()

Comment: no worries i have resolved the issue on the new error, laravel 8 has changed array_get() to Arr::get().